# Configure sendmail to relay on an smtp server

Tags: smtp, email-server, sendmail

I'm using an ubuntu distribution.

And I installed the sendmail with apt, and edited the `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`, and added the lines

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `ssl0.ovh.net')
FEATURE(`authinfo')
```

before the line

```
define(`_USE_ETC_MAIL_')dnl
```

And also configured the authentication (/etc/mail/authinfo):

```
AuthInfo:ssl0.ovh.net "U:myemail@mydomain.com" "P:123456" "M:PLAIN"
```

and run `m4 sendmail.mc >sendmail.cf` and `service sendmail restart`

I created a file to test it `email.txt`:

```
To: one@ofmyemail.com
From: my@email.com
Subject: Foo Bar

Hello
(empty line)
```

and I test it with: `cat email.txt | /usr/lib/sendmail -bm -t -v`

And it fails with:

```
one@ofmyemail.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
one@ofmyemail.com... Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
```

Why is it connecting with 127.0.0.1 instead of the external smtp server (ssl0.ovh.net)?

Comment: Is the `sendmail` service even running (`service sendmail status`)?

Answer (score 1):

Sendmail had used to be installed as set root uid program. Sendmail-8.12+ is no longer (by default) installed as set root uid program to avoid security risk.

Sendmail executed by non root user passes messages to sendmail daemon running with root privileges at 127.0.0.1:25.  Sendmail executed by non root user uses `/etc/mail/submit.cf` instead of `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf`.

https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/security/secure-install/

---

To test your sendmail.cf configuration as root execute the command below (your test command with `-Am` added):

```
cat email.txt | /usr/lib/sendmail -Am -bm -t -v
```